# What is this strange floating frame in Chrome OS?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

I have a Samsung Chromebook Plus V2 and there's always this odd floating box that only shows when you find its edge and hover over it.

It's fully re-sizable, but seems to have no purpose. On the contrary, it is extremely annoying because if the item you want to click is underneath it, it blocks the cursor.

The cursor turns into a resize cursor and you can grab and drag it to resize. I don't get it.

I want it to go away.

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: >>floating box that only shows when you find its edge and hover over it.              So, to which edge (or where) would I move my cursor, to 'find its edge'?                     (Hopefully, one of us can re-recreate what you are seeing.)

Comment: I'd recommend to check the chrome task manager to see which programs and windows are open, that should give a hint.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a coincidence or not, but I swear it only shows up after launching the settings page for the first time after boot. It usually shows up as framing the bottom half of the screen so you can find it at the edge of the screen in the bottom half or by slowly moving the cursor down at roughly the half way (vertical) point of the screen until the cursor changes to a resize handle, then it appears. I've looked through the task manager many times and have experimentally killed processes and I still can't figure it out.